# Visual Debugging Helper - POST, variables, etc ( within Controllers in Play Framework )

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm curious if there is already existing library that I'm not aware of, for visual representation of request, or any other variables within Play Framework.

---

For example, in Python - it's possible to use pprint:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

---

Another example, in PHP - there is a var_dump or something like Kint:

http://raveren.github.io/kint/

---

To give a little bit more context of where it would be used - Controller (in this example I assume that fictional scala_or_play_visual_dump would either return or exit further execution):

```
 def displaySomething = Action {
     val x = List(1, 2, 3)

     // ??? - scala_or_play_visual_dump(x)

     Ok("This code shouldn't be executed...")
 }
```

and output (**in a browser!**, not log files) will be something like either Jupyter notebook produces, or pprint, or var_dump or Kint tool/library:

```
 List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Interesting thought - let us know if you find (or write!) something.

Comment: Something like `.flashing` in Play? But you have to print it [manually](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash#flash-scope) in template...